# How can I print unicode without using u'\uXXXX'

Tags: python, python-unicode

I'm trying to make a program to iterate through japanese characters (Python 2.7) and return/yield them in a printable format, but I cannot convert the hexadecimal numbers (3040-309f) into a format that can print the characters. I have found that using u'\u' works, but when I attempt to convert the numbers into that format using unicode('\u3040'), it is different from u'\u3040'. The code explains it better.

```
>>> s1 = u'\u309d'
>>> s2 = unicode("\u209d")
>>> print type(s1) == type(s2)
True
>>> print s1 == s2
False
>>> print s1, s2
ゝ \u209d
```

I have tried using UTF-8 and latin-1 for `s2` as the second argument, but It does nothing. Also, I found that you can do `u'\u{0}'.format(u'3040')`, but I cannot make `u'3040'` in my iterator, and `u'\u{0}'.format(unicode('3040')` raises an error.

Comment: So where do you get your data *from*? Is that JSON perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

In *byte string literals*, the `\uhhhh` escape sequence is not interpreted, so you get a literal 6 characters instead.

Converting that to Unicode only decodes the string as ASCII data, not as a Python escape sequence.

You could decode from the `unicode_escape` encoding instead:

```
>>> "\u209d".decode('unicode_escape')
u'\u209d'
>>> print "\u209d".decode('unicode_escape')
₝
```

There are several downsides to this, however. Any other `\` escape sequences *also* get decoded:

```
>>> '\\n'
'\\n'
>>> '\\n'.decode('unicode_escape')
u'\n'
```

so you may have to replace backslashes with doubled backslashes first to come back on top with those literal backslashes retained:

```
>>> '\\n'.replace('\\', '\\\\').decode('unicode_escape')
u'\\n'
```

But be *very careful* that you are not in fact trying to treat *JSON data* as Python string literals. JSON *also* uses the same escape sequence format but should instead be treated as JSON; decode with `json.loads()` instead:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('"\u209d"')
u'\u209d'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasn't using JSON, and this answer really helped. I was getting my data by iterating through the unicode characters in order. (All characters from 3040 to 309f)

Comment: @Scarce573: you can use the `unichr()` to produce a character from an integer representing the codepoint.